# xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04 broke hardware acceleration

Tags: drivers, amdgpu, hardware-acceleration, hardware-enablement-stack, i915

I have been struggling to get my hybrid graphics (i915, amdgpu) to properly work in Ubuntu 18.04.

A few months ago, I installed the drivers from `ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`. While the Intel drivers seemed to work well, the DRI_PRIME=1 (amdgpu) failed to function properly.

1. I decided to continue looking for graphics solutions
2. It came to my attention that Oibaf considers 18.04 obsolete and suggests using HWE.
3. An Ubuntu 20.04 live USB worked flawlessly with both cards.

Seeing that I am tied to 18.04 by our tech stack, I cannot move to 20.04.

I ran the following:

```
$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```

Both completed successfully.

After rebooting, I noticed that Chrome/Chromium and Electron applications (Slack, VS Code, Zoom even?) exhibit extreme flickering, ghosting, screen tearing, and general artifacting while hardware acceleration is enabled. This appears to be a significant regression.

**Questions:**

1. How can I remedy this?
2. If there is no remedy, how can I properly diagnose the issue for a bug report?

---

```
linux-generic-hwe-18.04 (5.4.0.42.46~18.04.35)
xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04 (1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.3)

➜  ~ inxi -Gxxxz
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel vendor: Dell driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 chip ID: 8086:3ea0 
           Device-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Lexa XT [Radeon PRO WX 3100] vendor: Dell driver: amdgpu v: kernel 
           bus ID: 3b:00.0 chip ID: 1002:6985 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 compositor: gnome-shell v: 3.28.4 driver: amdgpu,ati,intel 
           unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz s-dpi: 96 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel UHD Graphics 620 (WHL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.8 compat-v: 3.0 direct render: Yes 

➜  ~ DRI_PRIME=1 inxi -Gxxxz
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel vendor: Dell driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 chip ID: 8086:3ea0 
           Device-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Lexa XT [Radeon PRO WX 3100] vendor: Dell driver: amdgpu v: kernel 
           bus ID: 3b:00.0 chip ID: 1002:6985 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 compositor: gnome-shell v: 3.28.4 driver: amdgpu,ati,intel 
           unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz s-dpi: 96 
           OpenGL: renderer: AMD Radeon Pro WX3100 (POLARIS12 DRM 3.35.0 5.4.0-42-generic LLVM 9.0.1) v: 4.5 Mesa 19.2.2 
           direct render: Yes
```

---

*Edit 1: spelling*

Comment: I just disable hardware acceleration in Chrome/Chromium & Firefox. It doesn't seem to change anything important and stops weird bugs from cropping up. Is that a realistic option for you?

Comment: @KGIII I've done so but unfortunately also experience really bizarre graphics artifacting. [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/idjcge/how_to_fix_this_bizarre_graphics_artifact_on/) is a screenshot.

Comment: Your link mentions something about the HWE stack, have you considered using Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer and dropping in a newer kernel? It's a bit drastic - but you can easily revert if there's a problem. If it's a problem, you just select the older kernel through GRUB because Ubuntu doesn't delete the older kernel and GRUB still sees it.